# Can I include a JavaFX LineChart in a JavaFX GUI

Tags: java, javafx, linechart, scene, gridpane

I would like to declare a JavaFX GridPane of two panels, the left one containing a push button. When the push button is clicked a  LineChart is displayed in the right hand panel. The coding would presumably look like this:

```
public class FormLineChart extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("A Title");
        //Create the grid for defining the GUI
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        // add gui objects to grid
        ...
        //Create the chart
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        ...
        // Create the series and display the lineChart
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 427, 319);
        //How do we add 'lineChart' to scene as well as keeping 'grid'?
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Specifically is it possible to combine 'grid' and 'lineChart' in one scene? At the moment only the GUI is displayed because on is forced to set the scene to the grid.

Comment: Put the line chart and the grid in another pane (of some kind) and make that pane the root of the scene. Or, just add the line chart to an appropriate location in the grid when the button is pressed.

Comment: It is actually as simple as `grid.add(lineChart, 0,1);`. You can simply add your `lineChart` directly to the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @James_D said you simply need another container to achieve that. A `Pane` can contain GUI controls as well as another `Pane`.

In the example below I put a `GridPane` with few buttons inside a `BorderPane` that divides the window into right and left part.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("A Title");

    // Root element
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    // GridPane
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.add(new Button("Button 1"), 0, 0);
    grid.add(new Button("Button 2"), 0, 1);
    grid.add(new Button("Button 3"), 0, 2);

    // Chart
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName("Chart");
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 5));
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 10));
    lineChart.getData().add(series);

    root.setLeft(grid);
    root.setRight(lineChart);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. I was fuzzy about how 'root' could be used to achieve what I needed, now its clear.